# How to tailor a prince 2 project as a software supplier and the PM

Tags: prince2

I am interested if anyone has tailored prince 2 to this purpose as many aspects of the project process do not seem applicable.  Such as assigning project board as this is done at the point of sale before I am involved and initiation doc etc.  any examples of tailored down method or advised would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Remember that PRINCE2 is a method/framework for you to work within. The only thing that is absolutely required is to work within the principles of PRINCE2 (focus on products, continual business justification, manage by stages, manage by exception, defined roles/responsibilities, learn from experience, tailor the method to your needs).

The specifics of tailoring would have to be geared to your project, but the PRINCE2 manual has a good section on tailoring of the method that could give you guidance. If you don't need so much control or the project is of lower risk/criticality you could, for example:

1. Merge roles within the project board (e.g. executive and senior user could be same person)
2. Merge roles within the project team (e.g. PM and project support could be same person)
3. Tailor the detail and/or formality required in managment products (e.g. checkpoint and highlight reports)

Regarding the Project Board, also remember that membership does not have to be static. If it makes sense to change one or more members you should. The important thing like Iain said is that all interests (user, supplier and executive) are represented.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I've understood the question correctly. I've been dealing with the same question from a Digital Agency perspective - working on major web development projects.

PRINCE2's conception of "customer" is not ideal in a software supplier / customer relationship.

We decided NOT to put the client on the Project Board because we don't want to bother the client with project minutiae, our internal resource anxieties. Most importantly though, this maintains a contractual fence between client and us (the supplier). A healthy project has everyone's interests aligned, but placing the client on the project board potentially places too much power with the client, which could lead to mission creep.

We call the "Project Executive" the "Product Owner" - this is usually the senior Account Director who knows the client the best. They represent the client in the process, but also act as the conduit if there are major budget/scope issues to resolve.

I don't know if this is the "right" way of doing things - but it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you are trying to look at this as a single project, where perhaps it should be considered as two?

1. Developing the product that will be sold;
2. Implementing the product in the client's environment.

If I am right in my assumption, then you certainly can tailor each of these separately: just be sure that you keep a clear focus on the deliverables for the two different clients (internal and external) that correspond to the project that you are running.

At the point of sale, the client should be creating the project board, and you, as PM, will be invited to be involved, but remember that in a Prince 2 environment, the Project Board is responsible for the project, and the PM is the conduit through which delivery is achieved... This is not how it works using different project models, where the PM is solely responsible.